# How to make SQL like condition search only show a specific set of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a query where i am getting informations from contacts table which looks like this
[image]

And numbers table which looks like this
[image]

Im getting contact information with its numbers while searching currently the code lookslike this

```
SELECT contacts.id, fname, lname, email, address,uid,uniqid,
       group_concat(distinct pnumber order by pnumber) c,cid
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN numbers
    ON contacts.uniqid = numbers.cid
WHERE fname LIKE '%' OR lname LIKE '%' OR pnumber LIKE '%' AND contacts.uid = 8 
group by id, fname, lname, email, address, uid, uniqid, cid
```

Im trying to search for keyword and get only the contacts that belong to that user "uid" which i set 8 for example in here. Apparently it returns this
[image]

Why the AND condition doesn't work and how can i get contacts that belong only to specific uid?

Note:Sorry for posting images, there was no way for me to generate ascii for this tables since they are too long

Comment: why the three LIKE conditions with a wildcard? They mean "any fname, any lname or any pnumber. You can skip them

Comment: @LelioFaieta, I agree, looks strange. That's the same as `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @LeiloFaieta i put it like that just for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
WHERE (fname LIKE '%' OR lname LIKE '%' OR pnumber LIKE '%') AND contacts.uid = 8
```